# TLS 1.2 client cipher list in clientHello is coming different order for different https server hosts

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat6, tls1.2

I have https integration with two host server and I am using java 1.6 and provided cipher using the `-Dhttp.ciphers` list. we have added Strong cipher first and then added the weaker once. Assuming the order is been followed when we make the SSL connection.

What i observed in the SSL debug log whenever java application is making the connection to host A
Cipher list order is maintain as given in `-D` option in client Hello message.
Here we are using `httpsURLconnection` to make a connection.

But when we make the SSL connection to host B cipher list in client hello message is getting changed. Weak cipher is coming before Strong cipher and as a result weak cipher is selected by the Server host B. Here we are making an use of Apache Default httpclient 3.1 to make https connection.

Any idea about why the order of weak ciphers is getting changed ?

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are asking and where you are looking for the cipher order. It might be useful to have the exact debug message you see. In general: the server decides which cipher gets used at the end and different servers might make different decisions even if the client offers always the same ciphers in the same order.

Comment: See this related question: https://serverfault.com/questions/316313